# How can I skip default pipeline on pull request?

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines, bitbucket-cloud

In the project I am currently working on, I want to run the bitbucket pipeline according to the following rules.

- Test and lint steps should run for each commit pushed to Branch.
- The test-with-coverage and lint steps must be run for each record
  opened with Pull Request.

The problem here is that if I push a commit to a branch that I have opened a pull request, the pipeline is triggered twice.

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step: *lint
    - step: *test
  pull-requests:
    '**':
      - step: *lint
      - step: *test-with-coverage
```

I looked for a way to skip default pipeline if a pull request exists, but I can't find it. I am open to suggestions and opinions.

Comment: Curious, but why wouldn't you want tests run when a pull request is updated? The PR is only updated if something changes, so you'd be skipping tests on those new commits - and letting potentially bad code through as a result.

Comment: I don't want to skip tests on pull request. However, if there is a PR, I want to run different pipeline. In branch, I only run tests. However, if there is PR, I want to run test with minimum code coverage limit (Only if there is a pr). I'll add sonarqube if there is a pipeline as well.

Comment: Did you figure it out maybe? I have exactly the same question :)

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't find any way to do this :(

Answer (score -1):

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step: *lint
    - step: *test
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      when: never
  pull-requests:
    '**':
      - step: *lint
      - step: *test-with-coverage
```

Comment: Where did you find the "rules:" block? I cant find anything about this and it does not work for me in my build. I do see some info about a "conditions" block https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/configure-bitbucket-pipelinesyml/ but while that is at least recognized as valid it still does not achieve the desired effect of above

Comment: I think @artak is referring to gitlab pipelines: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules